# Ordering column values with LINQ ignoring empty string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

How to Order column values with LINQ ignoring empty string values ?

Existing code for ordering

```
datatable.Select().OrderBy(u => u["ColName"]).ToArray();
```

Using above code, the empty string values listed first followed by the ordered list. 
But, I want to ignore empty string values to keep them in the same position.

Comment: What does keeping in same position mean? `["", "b","","c","a",""]` should become `["","a","","b","c",""]`?

Comment: simplest way is to check null or empty values in `OrderBy` Clause `OrderBy(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u["ColName"])`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, Yes exactly.

Comment: Extract the positions of all empty strings, order, then reinsert them. A custom comparison could work, but only by coincidence, since it's not possible to define a custom comparison that meets the rule of transitivity that way.

Comment: I am exporting the datatable content to excel as we are having empty rows in between. We need the empty rows as we seen in the datatable to be displayed in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var query = datatable.AsEnumerable();  // Or datatable.Select();

var sorted = query 
             .Where(u => (string) u["ColName"] != "")
             .OrderBy(u => u["ColName"]).ToArray();
var idx = 0;
var results = query 
              .Select(u => (string) u["ColName"] == "" ? u : sorted[idx++]);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer..

Comment: Thank You. It was working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
datatable.Select().OrderBy(u => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u["ColName"]).ToArray();
```

Comment: That will not preserve position of rows with empty values

Answer (score 0):

if it is a sting column - `datatable.Select().Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u["ColName"]) ).OrderBy(u => u["ColName"]).ToArray();`

Comment: error message saying "The best overload method for string.IsNullOrEmpty has some invalid arguments"

Comment: I believe this will return a list without the empty values. According to comments OP wants the empty values included.

Comment: @JohnStephen - That's because `u["ColName"]` is an object. `IsNullOrEmpty` expects a `string`. You must either call `as string`, `ToString()` or make it a string in another way. But beware if it's null.

Comment: the problem is the you need to call u["ColNAme"].ToString(), because string.IsNullOrEmpty expects strings not objects.

Answer (score 0):

Extract Array without empty values: `{ "", "2", "", "1", "4", "3" } -> { "2", "1", "4", "3" }`

```
val toOrder = datatable.Select().Where(u => u["ColName"] != "");
```

Sort this one: `{ "2", "1", "4", "3" } -> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }`

```
val ordered = toOrder.OrderBy(u => u["ColName"]);
```

Insert into old list: `{ "1", "2", "3", "4" } -> { "", "1", "", "2", "3", "4" }`

```
val newArray = datatable.Select();
int orderedIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < newArray.Count; i++)
{
    if (newArray[i]["ColName"] != "")
    {
        newArray[i] = ordered[orderedIndex++];
    }
}
```

Not 100% LINQ, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own (extension) method which does such type of sorting (for simplicity it is for sequence of DataRows, but you can create generic version with same approach):

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> SortByNonEmpty(
      this IEnumerable<DataRow> source, string columnName)
{
    var query = from r in source
                let value = r.Field<string>(columnName)
                where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
                orderby value
                select r;

    using (var ordinalEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var sortedEnumerator = query.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (ordinalEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((ordinalEnumerator.Current.Field<string>(columnName))))
               yield return ordinalEnumerator.Current;

           sortedEnumerator.MoveNext();
           yield return sortedEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

It uses two enumerators - `ordinalEnumerator` which enumerates sequence in original order, and `sortedEnumerator` which enumerates sorted sequence with non-empty values in column. I.e. if you'll think about original values as `["", "b","","c","a",""]` then first enumerator will enumerate all elements in original order. Second enumerator will produce only elements `["a","b","c"]`.

Then we just check each item in source sequence. If it has empty value in column, then we just return that row (thus preserving order of empty values). Otherwise we take next item from ordered sequence. Thus non-empty values will come in sorted order.

Usage:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().SortByNonEmpty("ColName")
```

---

Test

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, "");
table.Rows.Add(2, "b");
table.Rows.Add(3, "");
table.Rows.Add(4, "c");
table.Rows.Add(5, "a");
table.Rows.Add(6, "");

table.AsEnumerable().SortByNonEmpty("Name")
```

Output

```
[
  { "Id": 1, "Name": "" },
  { "Id": 5, "Name": "a" },
  { "Id": 3, "Name": "" },
  { "Id": 2, "Name": "b" },
  { "Id": 4, "Name": "c" },
  { "Id": 6, "Name": "" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//On input  { "", "a", "", "c", "f", "b", "", "e", "d" }
//On output { "", "a", "", "b", "c", "d", "", "e", "f" }
public static List<string> Sort(List<string> l)
{
    var filtered = l
        .Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
        .Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.s))
        .OrderBy(o => o.s)
        .ToArray();

    var indexed = filtered
        .Select(o => o.i)
        .OrderBy(i => i)
        .Select((n, i) => new { n, filtered[i].s })
        .ToArray();

    return l
        .Select((s, i) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                return s;
            return indexed.First(o => o.n == i).s;
        })
        .ToList();
}
```